# Exchange Powershell Export to pst size

Tags: exchange, powershell, mailbox

I'm using  exchange powershell to export exchange mailbox to pst.

I'm using this command:

> New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox user -FilePath [path]

This works but one user was 30GB and each export I do for this user errors out on import. What I want to do is export this users mailbox to pst PER 2GB and import each 2GB pst to new mailbox. I've used content Filtering, but I do not believe this is not an option. Maybe I am wrong?

**How can I export 1- 30GB Exchange mailbox into 15- 2GB pst files?**

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, but you can try to perform the export on a specific Exchange CAS server and export to a local drive on this CAS server like on [this TechNet Blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/richardroddy/archive/2011/02/16/exchange-2010-sp1-problems-exporting-large-mailbox-to-pst.aspx) to make sure the export runs better and faster:

> So, we did 2 things:
>
> 1) We created a folder/share on CAS server 1, and gave the Exchange Trusted Subsystem Read/Write access to the share as directed in http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607299.aspx.
>
> 2) In our command we specified the new share as our file path, and also specified CAS 1 in the -MRSServer setting in our New-MailboxExportRequest command (i.e. New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox user1 -FilePath “\CAS1\PSTFileShare\user1.pst” -MRSServer CAS1.domain.com).

Answer (score 0):

You can try Command to Export all content from UserMailbox1's mailbox received between 02/02/05 and 02/05/05 to a folder called User1Data in the UserMailbox2's mailbox:

Export-mailbox -id UserMailbox1 –StartDate "02/02/05" –EndDate "02/05/05" -TargetFolder 'User1Data' -TargetMailbox UserMailbox2

**Can be used as Alternative Solution:** Since Exchange Application doesn't offer to option to Split file while exporting data into PST Forma. You can Check this utility [Link](http://technews2day.com/export-large-exchange-mailbox-to-pst/) , hope works for Exchange user wants to export.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what Robinsan suggested, what I have done in the past is used the [contentfilter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/new-mailboxexportrequest) switch and specified time frames to split up large mailboxes into multiple PSTs.

You still don't have the granular control of specifying the exact size you want... however, it's the next best alternative (in my opinion).

It would be something like this:

```
New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox Tony -ContentFilter {(Received -gt "01/01/2018") -and (Received -lt "01/31/2018")} -FilePath "\\SERVER01\PSTFileShare\Tony_Jan2018.pst"

New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox Tony -ContentFilter {(Received -gt "02/01/2018") -and (Received -lt "02/28/2018")} -FilePath "\\SERVER01\PSTFileShare\Tony_Feb2018.pst"
```